# Export PDF blade view using laravel-dompdf

Tags: laravel

i try to export a blade view using the package from : https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

but i get an error `array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array`

here my controller :

```
public function ExportPDF($licencie)
    {

        $pdf = PDF::loadView('licencie_structure.show', $licencie);
        return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');

    }
```

here my route :

```
Route::get('/export/pdf/{licencie}',
    [
        'as' => 'export.pdf',
        'uses' => 'LicencieStructureController@ExportPDF'
    ]);
```

here my view :

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="box box-info">
                <div class="box-header">
                    <h3 class="box-title">Fiche Licencie N° {{$licencie->num_licence}}</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="box-body">
                <div class="pull-right"><img src="http://localhost/adminlte/public/uploads/{{$licencie->lb_photo}}" class="img-thumbnail" style="width: 250px; height: 250px; margin-right: 50px"></div>
                <p>Statut : {{$licencie->statut_licence->lb_statut}} <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Une licence peu possède un des trois status suivant : Gratuit , Non Payé , A Renouveller">?</a></p>
                <p>Nom : {{$licencie->lb_nom}}</p>
                <p>Prenom : {{$licencie->lb_prenom}}</p>
                <p>Fonction : {{$licencie->activite_licencie->lb_activite}} </p>
                <p>Date de naissance : {{$licencie->dt_naissance}}</p>
                <p>Ville de naissance : {{$licencie->lb_ville_naissance}}</p>
                <p>Code Postal : {{$licencie->cd_dept_naissance}} </p>
                <p>Adresse Email : {{$licencie->adresse_email}} </p>
                <p>Pays de naissance : {{$licencie->pays->fr}}</p>
                <p>Licence Crée le : {{$licencie->created_at}}</p>
                <p>Licence enregistré pour la Saison : {{$licencie->saison->lb_saison}}</p>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="box box-info">
            <div class="box-header">
                <h3 class="box-title">Actions</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">
                {!! link_to_route('export.pdf', 'Export to PDF', [$licencie] , ['class' => 'btn btn-info'])!!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

someone knows why i get this error ? thanks a lot in advance .

Comment: Issue, appears to be here: `$pdf = PDF::loadView('licencie_structure.show', $licencie);`...is $licencie an array?

Comment: Try `$pdf = PDF::loadView('licencie_structure.show', (array) $licencie);`...WAIT...what is `$licencie`?

Comment: thanks for your reply ! $licencie is an object ! i tried your code know i get Undefined variable: licencie

Comment: Object...? How? in exportPDF, what shows when you `return $licencie;` - first line in method.

Comment: i updated my view maybe you will see better

Comment: It doesn't. See my previous comment please. Looks like `$licencie` is just an ID.

Comment: when i do : return $licencie i get "16" , it's the id of the object

Comment: Exactly. I'll write an answer. You need to get an object first ;) Right now you're just passing an ID string to the view - which won't work.

Comment: Oh yes i see , wait your answer gonna be perfect if you can show my how to achieve that !!! because i don't know here i need to get the object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, you're passing an `ID` string to the `PDF::loadView()` method. You first need to grab the licencie object. Try the below:

**Note, I assumed `Licencie` is the model. If not, change that portion.**

```
use App\Licencie;

public function ExportPDF($licencie)
{
    $licencie = Licencie::find($licencie)->first();
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('licencie_structure.show', compact('licencie'));
    return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');

}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , now i get my object but i get this error Undefined variable: licencie (View: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/FFR13BACKUP/resources/views/licencie_structure/show.blade.php)

Comment: the error seems to come from this line $pdf = PDF::loadView('licencie_structure.show', $licencie);

Comment: i updated my post you can see my show view at the top of the page where i posted the question

Comment: Somewhere in your `show.blade.php` file, you're not specifying `$licencie` properly

Comment: Confused... `licencie_structure.show` view is the code in your question? You're trying to export this to a PDF? With actions section and button?

Comment: yes i try to export licencie_structure.show to a pdf   {!! link_to_route('export.pdf', 'Export to PDF', [$licencie] , ['class' => 'btn btn-info'])!!}

Comment: Create a new view for exporting. Sloppy otherwise. Just copy the view and create a new file, i.e. `export.blade.php`, and remove that actions/button code.

Comment: i want to get a pdf with all the values like {{$licencie->num_licence}} and all others who are displayed in my view

Comment: Sure, just add those to a new `export.blade.php`. In fact, create this file and just put `<p>test</p>` to make sure it works. Then `<p>{{ $licencie }}</p>` and take it from there. It both those tests work, you're good to go. ;)

Comment: it's working with <p>test</p> i get a pdf file with "test" but not working with <p>{{ $licencie }}</p> i get the same error Undefined variable: licencie (View: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/FFR13BACKUP/resources/views/licencie_structure/export.blade.php)

Comment: This still exists in exportPDF method right? $licencie = Licencie::find($licencie)->first();

Comment: totaly Mike , i still have in my controller  $licencie = LicencieStructure::find($licencie)->first();

Comment: I know what it is...check my new edit. 99% sure this was the problem. i.e. this line: `$pdf = PDF::loadView('licencie_structure.show', compact('licencie'));`

Comment: you are the man Mike !! it's seems to work i only got another error file_put_contents(/var/folders/y7/x9xvd58s3jv2cm4xpc7q0j0c0000gn/T/9eef2f284b559363521531be5608153f): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Comment: What's file is causing that? Says permission denied. So likely folder permissions.

Comment: it's seems i don't have the permissions to /vendor/dompdf/dompdf/lib/fonts/

Comment: FontMetrics.php is the file who got the error i tried chmod -R 777 vendor/dompdf/dompdf/lib/fonts but no result at the moment ! i'm on it !!!!

Comment: No prob! Good luck!